# Distribute iText.sharp PDF Merger Files

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I need to send my app to others and am using the iText.sharp library to merge PDF files.

What DLL's do I need to include in my distribution package?

Comment: You need to build a deployment.  How you do that is up to you and will require some research on your part.  Few options are MS Setup and Deployment project, OneClick, Wix, Inno.  Or you just copy everything and register everything needing registered manually

Answer (score 0):

I found the 2 DLL's that were needed out of the dozen or so from the package that made this work, itextsharp.dll and BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).